# How does this JavaScript numeric compare function actually work?

Tags: javascript, function, sorting, integer, compare

I understand that to sort integers, I need to pass a compare function to sort() like so:

```
function(a, b){return a-b}
```

But what I'm wondering is how this actually *works*.  Meaning, if the result of a-b is negative, then b is sorted ahead of a, and if a-b is positive, then a is sorted ahead of b?  Is that right?  What happens if a-b = 0?

Comment: Then the numbers are the same, and it doesn't matter which goes first. It's [pretty well documented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description).

Answer (score 3):

That's a common pattern for sorting APIs.  If the returned value is 0, that means that the items are (for the purposes of ordering) equal.

In practice, the behavior of a sort function with equal keys is of some importance. A sort that leaves entries in the order they were in (relative to each other) when the keys are equal is called a **stable** sort.  In JavaScript, the `.sort()` API is explicitly specified as not necessarily being stable. That means that the sort function *might* leave you with an array wherein two elements that compared as equal are swapped when the sort is complete.

That behavior has an effect on how you use the `.sort()` function. Let's say you have a list of objects:

```
var list = [{
  firstName: "Louis",
  lastName: "Adams",
  // ...
}, {
  // ...
}];
```

So, objects with a first name field and a last name field. If the JavaScript `.sort()` API were required to be stable, then you could sort the list in a way that people would expect it to be sorted by doing this:

```
function ocompare(key, o1, o2) {
  return o1[key] < o2[key] ? -1 :
         o1[key] > o2[key] ? 1 :
         0;
}
list.sort(function(o1, o2) {
  return ocompare("firstName", o1, o2);
});
list.sort(function(o1, o2) {
  return ocompare("lastName", o1, o2);
});
```

That is, you could sort on the first name, and then sort on the last name, and you'd have a list sorted by last names, and you'd be sure that "Adams, John" would be in the list before "Adams, Zach". (Note that the *first* thing we sort on is the *less* important key.)

However, the JavaScript `.sort()` API is not necessarily stable, so you can't rely on that. Instead, you have to do all the ordering comparisons you want in a single pass through `.sort()`:

```
function ocompare(o1, o2) {
  var keys = [];
  for (var i = 2; i < arguments.length; keys[i] = arguments[i], ++i);

  for (i = 0; i < keys.length; ++i) {
    if (o1[keys[i]] < o2[keys[i]])
      return -1;
    if (o1[keys[i]] > o2[keys[i]])
      return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
list.sort(function(o1, o2) {
  return ocompare(o1, o2, "lastName", "firstName");
});
```

Note that this (while a bit more involved) might be faster than doing the two-pass approach that relies on a stable sort, because no comparison is necessary when the last name fields differ.

Comment: I tend to copy stuff out of the `arguments` object as a habit; that's not really necessary here but I think it makes it neater. In ES2015 it'd be possible to use the `...` notation.

Answer (score 1):

> Meaning, if the result of a-b is negative, then b is sorted ahead of a, and if a-b is positive, then a is sorted ahead of b? Is that right?

It's the other way round. If the return value is negative, `a` is put before `b`.

> What happens if a-b = 0?

It means the values are equal and their relative order does not matter.

From the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

> If `compareFunction` is supplied, the array elements are sorted according to the return value of the compare function. If `a` and `b` are two elements being compared, then:
>
> - If `compareFunction(a, b)` is less than 0, sort a to a lower index than b, i.e. a comes first.
> - If c`ompareFunction(a, b)` returns 0, leave a and b unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different elements. Note: the ECMAscript standard does not guarantee this behaviour, and thus not all browsers (e.g. Mozilla versions dating back to at least 2003) respect this.
> - If `compareFunction(a, b)` is greater than 0, sort b to a lower index than a.